# How to Create wcf service or web service that update database logs table?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ftp, ftp-client

Scenario:
I need make web service that always run on main computer or server.
When user finish some action i need update sql\Access table (insert to logs table)
the client have winforms that communicate with the service but i dont understand how make connection with Client to service with FTP Techonology/
Any Ideas to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the service to run every 1 minute and to check if some value in the database was change by the user. In case that the value changed so it will do whatever you want (insert the new rows). But it is not must to be wcf, you can also using win service instead.